# SonarLint hint hiding Eclipse tooltip

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

I'm using `SonarLint 1.3` in `Eclipse Mars`. My problem is when there's an SonarLint issue it prevents every other tooltip from appearing.

Example: as you can see tooltip for `Hashtable` is not shown because of SonarLint hint.

[image: SonarLint issue hiding Eclipse tooltip]

Is there a way to show both Eclipse tooltips and SonarLint hints?

Comment: Eclipse's tooltip also has the option to press F2 for focus. From your snippet I can see that SonarLint also as it. So, what happens when you press F2?

Comment: The same as in Eclipse tooltips: it changes appearance from tooltip to window so you can focus, resize, etc. it. But no way to see other tooltips.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is standard Eclipse behavior that problem marker tooltips will have higher priority than JDT Hover tooltips.

If you want to force JDT tooltips to be displayed it is possible using some keybord shortcuts. Look in Eclipse preferences for Java -> Editors -> Hovers

For example to see the Javadoc tooltip that is displayed on Hashtable when there is no SonarLint issue you should press Ctrl+Shift

Example:
[image]

Comment: Since eclipse's tooltips are actually full-featured windows (once you click inside the tootltip or you press F2), they should have added a discoverable button in the tooltip's toolbar to allow switching between all the "announcers". Also, they could have mentioned the Ctrl+Shift shortcut just like they do for the "Press F2 to focus".

Comment: Note that it's super not intuitive they decided to put this in the Hovers pref page rather than in the standard Keys pref page. Also I couldn't find it in the help document.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I found is to "show view" javadoc. By doing this you will be able to see SonarLint tooltip and the code fragment-related javadoc in the javadoc view when you placed your cursor inside the code fragment. Yes, this is NOT actual "hovering", I know, but this is the only way I found so far.